# change width of indicators panel in gnome 3

Tags: gnome

How change the width of indicators panel in gnome 3? If there are a lot of them - they start shorting:/

There are some empty space on the left side of top panel - how to make them use it?

I could not find it in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`.

[image]

Also - how to hide the main application's panel("File", "Edit", "Search", etc.)? Ideally - behind the top edge of the screen, but may be there are some other ways.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and extension from the offsite named some-like `gnome bar horizontal spacing` helped me to solve that.

Comment: I have the same problem here. Unfortunately, reducing the spacing between icons doesn't solve the problem. Is there a way to move some of this indicator to the left side of the panel? Thanks!

Comment: @0R10N Hello, I do no use GNOME 3 for last year, so I am not sure, but year ago it was like there are no such possibility, or if it exists - it is hidden deep in configs and css files.